# Nginx Does Not Make POST request after redirect https (TOMCAT-NGINX)

Tags: nginx, tomcat

iam using tomcat server for my web application

when http://servername:80 POST request working perfectly but after SSL install (letsencrypt) it doesn't get and post-action as well as the post inline action

why https post method are not allow in nginx

is there any other method is avalable to do

[showing error like this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v6xAS.png)

```
server {
listen       80;
server_name servername.com;
root /var/lib/tomcat9/webapps/ROOT/;
return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {
listen       443;
 location / {
              proxy_pass_header Server;
proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
#proxy_method $request_method;
proxy_http_version 1.1;
proxy_set_header Connection "";

proxy_buffering off;  #default on
proxy_request_buffering off;  #default on
proxy_buffer_size 32k;  #default 4k|8k
proxy_buffers 20 32k;  #default 8 4k|8k
proxy_connect_timeout 60s;  #default 60s
proxy_read_timeout 60s;  #default 60s
proxy_send_timeout 60s;  #default 60s
            proxy_pass         http://127.0.0.1:8080
        }
 

 listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/servername.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/servername.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
}
```

and i try some of these method too

```
location / {
    # index  index.html index.htm;
    try_files $uri $uri$args $uri/index.jsp /index.jsp =404;
}
```

Comment: help me to work with this

Comment: For redirecting POST requests you need to use 307 instead of 302 and 308 instead of 301.

Comment: i tried 307 return but still, show error like these https://i.stack.imgur.com/v6xAS.png my exact problem is post request not working in https

Comment: 308 redirect don't work too?

Comment: yes i tired that too that's why i raise the question here